# Как выводить ответ в столбик?

Tags: python

Разработать функцию для вывода на экран цифр (через пробел) натурального числа в прямом порядке. Применить эту функцию ко всем числам из интервала от А до В.

У меня выводится

```
1 0 1 1 1 2 1 3 1 4 1 5
```

а должно:

```
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
```

```
def function(a,b):
   while a<=b:
     for c in str(a):
        print (c, end = ' ')
     a=a+1
i=int(input('Введите 1 число '))
n=int(input('Введите 2 число '))
print (function(i,n))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def function(a,b):
   while a<=b:
     for c in str(a):
        print (c, end = ' ')
     a=a+1
     print()           # <---


print (function(10, 15))
1 0 
1 1 
1 2 
1 3 
1 4 
1 5
```

Answer (score 2):

https://ideone.com/YS5gWI

```
def solve(l, r):
  return '\n'.join([' '.join(list(str(x))) for x in range(l, r+1)])

l=int(input())
r=int(input())
print(solve(l, r))
```